# What causes "Found checksum error" when updating a deleted file on HDFS?

Tags: hdfs, checksum

When I deleted a file on HDFS, and then tried to upload an updated version (with the same name) to the HDFS, I got this checksum error:

[image]

The error message reads:

> org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumException: Checksum error: file:/root/Desktop/test_data/dupli.txt at 0 exp: 1607003671 got: -1788866132

How do I upload an updated version of file on HDFS?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with programming.

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434709/checksum-exception-when-reading-from-or-copying-to-hdfs-in-apache-hadoop